# What DPS characteristics does a DPS monk have?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Mists of Pandaria, monks will have DPS, tank and healing specs.  I know the monks are leather-wearing melee DPS, but I was wondering what DPS characteristics do they have:

- Is their resource limited?
- Is their resource generated by their own hits or does it generate automatically?
- Do their DPS start off slow and ramp up or can they DPS fully from the very beginning of a fight?
- Do they do lots of quick hits, ala rogues, or slower larger hits like Cat druids or some Warriors?
- Are they reliant on procs?

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to do: sum up monks based on your own experience with the class they happen to be most like, but like all DPS specs, they have their similarities and differences with all the DPS specs, and so there's no correctness criteria. If this was rephrased to ask a specific question about monk game mechanics for the purposes of comparing it to other classes (e.g., "How do monks limit skill usage? What's their resource system?"), it'd work better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Monk (DPS/Tank) resource system is much like the rogue resource system.

Monks have a pool of energy which fills automatically.  Monks build "chi" points by using energy abilities.

Rogue combo points are on the target, while Monk chi points are on the monk (you don't lose them when you switch target).  Rogue combo points go up to five and however many you have are fully spent when a finisher is used.  Monk chi points go up to four or five and chi abilities cost one or two points.

---

Monks are on the 1 second global cooldown (same as rogues).

Here is a sample of Monk abilities:

Chi generating moves

- Stance of the Fierce Tiger - increases Chi generated by Jab and Expel Harm by 1.
- Power Strikes (talent) - increases Chi generated by Jab by 1 (once per 20 seconds).
- Chi Brew (talent) - fills Chi to full (90 second cooldown)
- Jab - consumes 40 energy, grants 1 chi (2 with stance).  The name of this ability morphs with the equiped weapon. (example, it is called "Sever" with Axe equipped)
- Expel Harm - consumes 40 energy, grants 1 chi (2 with stance).  Heals yourself and damages target. 15 second cooldown.
- Spinning Crane Kick - consumes 40 energy, grants 1 chi. AOE attack.
- Crackling Jade Lightning - chance to generate 1 chi per tick, channeled, ranged.

Chi consuming abilities

- Touch of Death - consumes 3 Chi.  Instant kill. only usable on non-player targets who have equal or less health than you.  90 second cooldown.
- Tiger Palm - consumes 1 Chi.  grants Tiger Power (up to three stacks, ignore 5% armor for 20 seconds).
- Blackout Kick - consumes 2 Chi.  damages target
- Rising Sun Kick - consumes 2 Chi.  damages target and applies Mortal Wounds.  All nearby enemies take 10% more damage from your abilities for 15 seconds.
- Chi Burst (talent) - consumes 2 Chi, blasts all enemies and heals all allies between you and target.
- Chi Wave (talent) - consumes 2 Chi, bounces between targets within 20 yards up to 5 times, damaging enemies and healing allies. 8 second cooldown.

Monk's Mastery is called "Combo Breaker", which randomly makes the next Tiger Palm or Blackout Kick cost no Chi.

Comment: I would rather compare it as a rogue/paladin system combined. They have an energy pool but their chi I would compare to the holy power of a paladin because the difference is, as you say yourself, that the chi related to the monk and not the target, same for holy power :)